# Analog Switch cannot provide 0V output when OFF

Tags: ltspice, analog-switch

I'm trying to simulate in LTSPICE the following simple circuit, and I cannot get 0V output when the analog switch is open.

Can anyone please explain why?

[image]

Comment: Try to add a Vss (negativ supply) voltage source and reduce the "switch" signal level, to be lower than V+.

Comment: Unfortunately I did try with no luck :(

Comment: Set Vss to -8V and the switch signal to 5V.

Comment: Looks like a problem with the model to me, since the datasheet says "rail-to-rail" and it looks like you're operating within specs. Might want to ask at their support forum: https://ez.analog.com

Comment: Looks like a diode. Too coincidental for my mind, seeing the pull-down value at about \$700\:\text{mV}\$. Try a lower \$V_\text{SS}\$ value and see what happens. (I don't expect analog to provide the detailed model inside. Sadly.) Also, try out a smaller value for your pull-down. Say, \$100\:\Omega\$? See if that helps, too. It may be something else, entirely. Good catch, though. I'll be interested to see details here.

Answer (score 3):

The datasheet is not clear on this it guarantee's leakage current, but it stops short at 1V. There are no figures that would suggest the leakage decreases or increases, but I suspect that it would increase because the fet's cant turn fully off if the switch voltage and the Vdd voltage are equal.

The leakage below is for 5V to 0V which is a similar situation as 8V.

[image]
Source: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG1611_1612_1613.pdf

Comment: It's a little bit shady that they wouldn't report the leakage below 1V, it looks like this is not a good single side switch, there are better ones out there if you only need single side.